# How to make an image-covered background in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, material-ui

I have an image and i need to make it cover all of the background.

The problem is, that for some reason the image isn't covering all of the background,
and it always stops somwhere where i put another object, and never goes farther then this.

Im using material ui and my code looks like this

```
import { Image } from "../images";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
Background: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    justifyItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundImage:  `url(${Image})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: '50% 10%',
  }
})

function Login() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.Background}>
       <TextField></TextField>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the result i get:
[image]

Comment: Codesandbox link ?

Comment: doesn't have one, and unfortunately, it requires a lot to open a react project there rn. that's why i've brought here the entire code. is there a specific thing you wanted to check that i didn't bring here?

Comment: ok wait, i found out a way to do that. here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-perlman-vggskp?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this style

```
Background: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    justifyItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    backgroundImage: `url(${asd})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "50% 10%"
  }
```

Comment: setting the backgroundSize as "cover" didn't help :(

Comment: I have added height: "100vh",